# Unable to decrypt using RSA encryption through stored keys in files

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a message within java using RSA encryption. We have stored our keys as bytes in their own respective files, and load the contents of these files to be used as the keys in our encryption/ decryption methods. However, when I compile the code, I receive error:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must be longer than 256
> bytes.

Our generateKeys and encryption/ decryption methods read:

```java
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class Encryption {
    static File filepath = new File("..\\..\\..\\");
    public static void generateKeyPair() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    
        PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();

        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "rsaPublicKey"));
            dos.write(publicKey.getEncoded());
            dos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (dos != null) {
                try {
                    dos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "rsaPrivateKey"));
            dos.write(privateKey.getEncoded());
            dos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (dos != null)
                try {
                    dos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    public static KeyPair getKeyPair() throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytesPublic = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath + "rsaPublicKey"));
        byte[] keyBytesPrivate = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath + "rsaPrivateKey"));

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        
        EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytesPublic);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytesPrivate);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        KeyPair keys = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);

        return keys;
    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt (String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());

        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String Decrypt (byte[] cipherTextArray, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        
        byte[] decryptedTextArray = cipher.doFinal(cipherTextArray);
        
        return new String(decryptedTextArray);
    }
}
```

We then call these methods, where we receive our error:

```java
KeyPair pair = Encryption.getKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();

// plugin.getLogger().info(chatMessage);
ids = chatMessage.substring(chatMessage.length() - 9, chatMessage.length() - 1);
plugin.getLogger().info(ids);
chatMessage = chatMessage.substring(0, chatMessage.length() - 10);
chatMessage = Encryption.Decrypt(chatMessage.getBytes(), privateKey);
server.broadcastMessage(chatMessage);
byte[] ctArray = Encryption.Encrypt("Sent message successfully.", publicKey);
encrypted_return = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ctArray);
send(encrypted_return);
```

Comment: At what line in your code you receive the error? Are you for sure that the error message is "Data must be longer than 256 bytes" and not "Data must be NOT longer than 256 bytes" ? BTW: converting strings to bytes ("plainText.getBytes()") without a given charset may cause errors when changing the platform (defaults may change).

Comment: With the code provided, I cannot reproduce the error. Encrypting and decrypting using your methods works in general, but I obviously have no valid chat message from your program I could decrypt.

Aside from that, you probably don't want to encrypt chat messages using RSA, because you are limited to a specific amount of bytes you can encrypt. Encrypting multiple blocks using ECB is a bad idea (see examples on https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Code_Book_Mode )